# How to add custom text on ScreenSaverView in Swift?

Tags: swift, macos, nsview, screensaver

Trying to make `.saver` in swift for MacOS, But don't know how to add custom `text` or `Label` on `ScreenSaverView` class which is the subclass from `NSView`.

Below is my piece of code, but doesn't work.

```
private var text: CATextLayer!

override func draw(_ rect: NSRect) {
    // Draw a single frame in this function
    self.layer?.backgroundColor = .init(red: 142/255, green: 167/255, blue: 125/255, alpha: 1)
    text.removeFromSuperlayer()
    text.string = "Test"
    text.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 200, height: 100)
    text.foregroundColor = .white
    text.backgroundColor = .clear
    self.layer?.addSublayer(text)

 }
```

Comment: What doesn't work?  What is the thing that you so-call clockText?  What is 'custom text?  A string?  An NSTextField object?  An NSTextView object?

Comment: Its `CATextLayer` text. Just updated question

Comment: Why are you using a CATextLayer object on an NSVIew object?  If you just want to draw a string on an NSView object, why don't you use NSAttributedString?  Or add an NSTextField object as a subView?

Comment: Got it. Use NSTextField will solve my problem. Thanks @ElTomato